# Is an array initialized from a string literal identical to one initialized from individual characters?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

There are two arrays:

```
char a[] = "Nice you!";     
char b[] = {'N', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!'};
```

I think `a[]` and `b[]` are exactly the same. So here's my code to see what is after the final element of each array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[] = "Nice you!";
    char b[] = {'N', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!'};

    char *pa;
    char *pb;
    pa = a;
    pb = b;
    printf("*(pa + 9)= %d\n", *(pa + 9));
    printf("*(pb + 9)= %d\n", *(pb + 9));

    return 0;
}
```

Is my understanding correct? I am not so sure and need confirmation.

Comment: `a` terminates with zero character, so it is one character longer than `b`.

Comment: [See here what is \0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)

Comment: Conventionally, `*(pa + 9)` is written using array index notation: `pa[9]`.

Comment: `*(pb+9)` is undefined behavior so whatever output you get is meaningless.

Answer (score 7):

It's almost the same.

This array is `NUL` terminated:

```
char a[] = "Nice you!";
```

This array is not `NUL` terminated:

```
char b[] = {'N', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!'};
```

The exact equivalent of array `a` is this:

```
char c[] = {'N', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!', 0};
                                                         ^ NUL terminator
```

In your code `*(pb + 9)` accesses one element beyond the array, therefore the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Comment: *NULL terminator

Comment: @Alan negative, don't mix up the `NULL` pointer and the `NUL` character, it's two different things.

Comment: @Alan as Jabberwocky says `NULL` is different to the `NUL` character, but confusingly "the null character" is the same thing as `NUL`. So you can say "NUL terminator" or "null terminator", both are correct (but "NULL terminator" isn't). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Answer (score 6):

> *I think a[] and b[] are exactly the same....*

No, they are not same. The difference is null terminating character.

This

```
char a[] = "Nice you!";
```

is equivalent to this

```
char a[] = {'N', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!', '\0'};
                                                          ^^^
```

The last element of array `a` is null terminated character - `'\0'`.

In this

```
char b[] = {'N', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!'};
```

the last element of array `b` is `'!'` character.

Array `a` is a **string**<sup>1)</sup> and array `b` is **array of characters**.

When we omit the dimension, compiler computes it for us based on the size of the initializer. So, the dimension of array `a` will be `10` whereas the dimension of array `b` will be `9`.

In your program, you are accessing the array `b` beyond its size using pointer `pb`:

```
printf("*(pb + 9)= %d\n", *(pb + 9));
```

`*(pb + 9)` -> `p[9]` -> accessing `10th` element of array `b` causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you try to access array out of bound.

---

1) C language does not have native *string* type. In C, strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `a` and `b` are same.

There is a slight difference though. The array `a` will have `Null Character` ie `\0` in it's last location.

Where as the array `b` will be having `!` at it's last index

Comment: `NULL` and `\0` are not exactly the same. `'\0'` is an `int` but `NULL` is usually a `(void*) 0`.

Comment: yeah. Sorry. I meant to say null character

Answer (score 1):

> **I think a[] and b[] are exactly the same**

No, they're not the same.

```
char a[] = "Nice you!";
```

Is a character array that meets all the criteria for a C "string" - it's terminated implicitly by a `'\0'` character.  You can safely print it with calls such as `puts( a )`.

```
char b[] = {'N', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!'};
```

is just a character array.  It is **not** implicitly terminated with a `'\0'` character.  Trying to print it with something like `puts( b )` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, `a[]` and `b[]` are almost same.

Here, `a[]` is a string ( though there is no data type in C named string ) . It acts like an automatic array of characters when you declare `a[]` like this `char a[] = "Nice you!"` and compiler puts a `NUL` (`'\0'`) which defines the end of the string.

But, when you are declaring something like this `char b[] = {'N', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!'}`   it means you very declaring an array of character in your way , not in the way of built in `char` array. So, it doesn't hold a `NUL` (`'\0'`) after `'!'` . In fact what the second array `b[]` will print is undefined .

Thank you...!

Comment: It is not `NULL`, `NULL` is a null pointer constant; you mean `NUL`.

Comment: would you please tell the diffrence between `NULL` and `NUL` ?

Comment: `NULL` is a macro defined in `<stdlib.h>` which expands to a null pointer constant. The null character is also known as [`NUL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). Of course there is no constant by the name `NUL` in headers - use `0` or `'\0'` for *that*.